# Symfony 2 | HWIOAuthBundle - How to create custom resource owner?

Tags: php, symfony, hwioauthbundle

I started to implement HWIOAuthBundle and want to create my own custom resource owner. However I'm unclear about the file/directory structure.

Where would I need to place my files to take advantage of the bundle?

Answer (score 4):

I overrode the HWIOAuthBundle linkedin resource owner, because I needed to handle connection exceptions.
You can use a compiler pass to do this:

```
namespace UserAccountBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class OverrideServiceCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('hwi_oauth.resource_owner.linkedin');
        $definition->setClass('UserAccountBundle\OAuth\MyLinkedInResourceOwner');
    }
}
```

Then in your bundle:

```
namespace UserAccountBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use UserAccountBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\OverrideServiceCompilerPass;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class UserAccountBundle extends Bundle
{

    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new OverrideServiceCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

More on bundle overrides:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Bundle doesn't support custom resource owners without editing the bundle directly (this is just at first glance, I've never actually used this bundle).

The oauth.xml file (https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/oauth.xml) links to each of the existing resource owners, so I guess you could take a look at one of the ones linked in here that would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [bundle documentation](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/resource_owners/others.md) you can do that.

I believe that is using the **GenericOauth2ResourceOwner** class located in vendor bundle directory HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\ResourceOwner.